# Career-question: Fields that combine Development Econ with Finance?

Tags: financial-economics, development-economics

I am studying economics, and am mainly fascinated by development economics and finance. What are some common career paths that involve the combination of these topics, and what subtopics can one study to strengthen oneself further in these fields?

Initially, I believe investment funds for developing countries is one possible field to look at, is this correct? What are the alternatives?

(I cannot find a "career"-tag so I apologize if this question if off-topic)

Comment: Perhaps a development bank would be interesting for you.

Comment: In many cases, developing countries lack infrastructure, financial resources, as well as the institutional framework to finance and build infrastructure. Learning about Infrastructure Finance would be a good start, whether you do it from a development bank or from an investment management company, or from a legal perspective, all would be useful.

Comment: I was thinking about something as the European Bank for Reconstruction and Development (EBRD) if you are interested in large investments; otherwise another area may be microfinance, that is really involved with micro-development